# Why won't GCC give errors passing a void * to a void** parameter?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, compiler-warnings

Shouldn't gcc give a type warning because a `void*` is being passed to a `void**` function parameter?

I tried clang, gcc4.8 and gcc9.  None of them seem to care:

`gcc -Wall -c t.c`

```c
void f(void *a)
{
}

void g(void **b)
{
    f(b);
}
```

#### Interestingly, the next example below does trigger this warning:

```c
t.c: In function ‘g’:
t.c:7:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘f’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  f(&b);
  ^
t.c:1:6: note: expected ‘void **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 void f(void **a)
```

```c
void f(void **a)
{
}

void g(char b)
{
    f(&b);
}
```

#### and this next one gives:

```c
t.c: In function ‘g’:
t.c:7:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘f’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  f(&b);
  ^
t.c:1:6: note: expected ‘void **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
 void f(void **a)
```

```c
void f(void **a)
{
}

void g(char *b)
{
    f(&b);
}
```

#### but this does not:

```c
void f(void *a)
{
}

void g(char b)
{
    f(&b);
}
```

so sometimes it cares about the pointer type being passed to the `void**` and sometimes it does not.  Thus, `void*` and `void**` are not always treated the same. Also `char**` won't cast to `void**`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `void *` type gets special treatment.  It basically means a pointer to some unknown type.  *Any* object pointer may be converted to or from a `void *` without a cast.

Comment: Do you mean that `void*` and `void**` are equivalent?

Comment: @Zakk Not at all.  A `void **` is a pointer to a specific type, namely a `void *`.  A `void *` can point to anything.

Comment: @Zakk, Only in the same sense that `struct Foo*` and `void *` are equivalent: You can convert them without an explicit cast. But that's where the equivalence ends. They might not even be the same size!

Comment: @dbush So, `f(b)` should have been `f(*b)`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Zakk Depends on what `f` is going to do with that parameter.  In this case the function has an empty body, so it doesn't really matter.  Look up the `qsort` function for an example of when you'd use a function with a `void *` parameter.

Comment: @Zakk, that is true.  I missed it when I wrote the code and was surprised the compiler didn't warn me, hence this question.  In my case it is memory allocation code.

Comment: dbush, see the update in the question.  Interesting about char** vs void**.

Comment: @KJ7LNW As I said, `void *` gets special treatment.  `void **` does not.